# How to make python say some text during while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to python, I started learning a couple days ago. I'm learning from this youtube video on python from "freecodecamp" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw&t=6831s). In the video he was teaching the audience how to make a guessing game. In the game, the user gets 3 chances to guess the secret word. I'm on the latest python version, and I wanted to know, how I can make it so that after every incorrect guess, it tells the user how many guesses they have left. Here is the code so far:

```
print("You need to guess a yellow fruit!")
secret_word = "Bananas"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out of guesses, you lose!")
else:
    print("You win!")
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: How about a `print()` statement? If this for some reason does not solve your problem, explain why in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to use an f string. F strings make it very easy to put variables into a string, and they are awesome. You would use something like `print(f"you have {guess_limit-guess_count} tries left!!")` on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this with a placeholder

```
print("You have {0} trys left!!").format(guess_limit-guess_count)
```

It will replace the `{0}` with whatever you put into the `format`

You can also read about different ways of doing this from [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)